# vue vite nginx html directories showing in private only

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vue-router, vite

I've created a vue project using Vue Router and Vite.
On the server I am using nginx.
My vue project has two routes only, login and create.

I also have a bunch of directories that I would like to be displayed which are not linked to vue router, but are in /var/www/html directory.

Problem is, when I visit those pages that are not linked to vue router, they are blank unless I hard reload with CTRL F5 or visit in incognito.

Any reasons why ?

```
server {
        # root /var/www/html/homepage;

        #listen 80;

        # index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;


        server_name homepage.domain.me www.domain.balog.me;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 7;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css text/javascript image/svg+xml image/x-icon application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss application/json;

        location / {
            root /var/www/html/homepage;
            index index.htm index.html;
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }


        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}

        location /api {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/api;
          proxy_redirect off;
        }

 #   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
 # ssl stuff down here
```

Comment: For anyone encountering this issue, here is what fixed it for me:
https://github.com/antfu/vite-plugin-pwa/issues/218